# Android layout properties

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to hide layout on button press,i.e, hide a linear layout where main.xml contains many linear layouts or is it to be done by some other layout please let me know
Below i have given an example of two linear layouts my question is
1.IS it correct
2on browse button press show linear layout2 ,hide linear layout1 and on send button press show linear layout1, hide linear layout2

Show me the relevant code to achieve this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <Button android:text="Browse" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <Button android:text="Send" android:id="@+id/send" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout llToHide = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
llToHide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To show it again call:

```
llToHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To make it as if it's not there call:

```
llToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The xml attribute to make a View visible, invisible, or gone is:

```
android:visibility="visible"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:visibility="gone"
```

The difference between "invisible" and "gone" is that "invisible" will not be shown but the rest of the layout will stretch or move as if it is there.  A view with a "gone" attribute will act as if it doesn't exist, but you can still change/manipulate it in case you want it seen eventually.

Comment: is there suppose to be a parent linear layout for the above two layouts.Or else i have seen i get an error

Comment: There should be a common, main view that everything falls in.

Comment: If i set it to view.GONE how to get it back?

Comment: Set it to view.Visible.  It doesn't actually delete the view.  It just adjusts the rest of the view as if it didn't exist.  In this case, you have two LinearLayouts, one on top the other.  If you set the first LinearLayout to Gone, it will disappear from the screen and the the second one will move up.  If you set the first LinearLayout to Invisible, the second will stay put but the first will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity you need this code:

```
  findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
             layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there suppose to be a parent linear layout for the above two layouts.Or else i have seen i get an error

Comment: As DeeV says - you should have only one master node - everything else should sit in that.  Put another layout (Relative, Linear etc) around what you have above and you should be fine.

Comment: If i set it to view.GONE how to get it back?